# Check user input for errors in bash script

Tags: bash, error-handling

kindly have a look at the following code:

```
  echo "nhat and betah for each element 
        TIPS: 4 REAL NUMBER for each element(eg, 1.0 0.0 1.0 .1)"
  read -a nbh
  if [ ${#nbh[@]} -ne 4 ]
  then 
    echo "Wrong!! "
  fi
```

This error check (if loop) will terminate the program, if I forget to give exactly 4 elements.
Is it possible, rather then terminating, give the user a chance again (and again)? i.e. basically go to the `read -a nbh` line again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `while "this condition is not matched"` can make it:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ ${#nbh[@]} -ne 4 ] <---- repeat until this is not true
do
  echo "nhat and betah for each element 
        TIPS: 4 REAL NUMBER for each element(eg, 1.0 0.0 1.0 .1)"
  read -a nbh
  if [ ${#nbh[@]} -ne 4 ]
  then 
    echo "Wrong!! "
  fi
done                       <---- finish while loop
```

#### Test

```
$ ./script
nhat and betah for each element 
        TIPS: 4 REAL NUMBER for each element(eg, 1.0 0.0 1.0 .1)
2 3
Wrong!! 
nhat and betah for each element 
        TIPS: 4 REAL NUMBER for each element(eg, 1.0 0.0 1.0 .1)
2 3 5 6
$
```

Comment: You doubled the code for the check (that `[ ${#nbh[@]} -ne 4 ]` here).  If this is to change in future versions, the patch will likely be forgotten in one of both places.  I think a `while true` would be better and then in the `else` branch have a `break` (not a Kitkat).

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf -v prompt '%s\n' "nhat and betah for each element" "TIPS: 4 REAL NUMBER for each element(eg, 1.0 0.0 1.0 .1)"
while read -p "$prompt" -a nbh; do
   ((${#nbh[@]}==4)) && break
   echo "Wrong!!"
done
```

(I've tried to render the script more acceptable regarding good practices).

Now you have a problem: how are you going to check that the user really inputs numbers? Let's pretend you have a function that can tell if a string is a valid representation of a number you accept. Let's call this function `banana` because it's a nice name. Then:

```
#!/bin/bash

banana() {
    # Like its name doesn't tell, this function
    # determines whether a string is a valid representation
    # of a number
    # ...
    # some wicked stuff here
    # ...
}

printf -v prompt '%s\n' "nhat and betah for each element" "TIPS: 4 REAL NUMBER for each element(eg, 1.0 0.0 1.0 .1)"
good=0
while ((!good)) && read -p "$prompt" -a nbh; do
    if ((${#nbh[@]}!=4)); then
        echo "Wrong!! you must give 4 numbers! (and I can count!)"
        continue
    fi
    for i in "${nbh[@]}"; do
        if ! banana "$i"; then
            echo "Your input \`$i' is not a valid number. It might be a valid banana, though. Check that with the local gorilla."
            continue 2
        fi
    done
    # If we're here, we passed all the tests. Yay!
    good=1
done

# At this point, you should check that we exited the loop because everything was
# valid, and not because `read` has an error (e.g., the user pressed Ctrl-D)
if ((!good)); then
    echo >&2 "There was an error reading your input. Maybe a banana jammed in the keyboard?"
    exit 1
fi

# Here you're safe: you have 4 entries that all are valid numbers. Yay.
echo "Bravo, you just won a banana!"
```

Now, for the function `banana`, you might want to use a regex (but then we'll have two problems, oh dear):

```
banana() {
    [[ $1 =~ ^-?([[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]+|[[:digit:]]+\.?[[:digit:]]*)$ ]]
}
```

Note that the scientific form is not supported here, so inputs like `1e-6` will not pass the test. If you need to also handle this, good luck, you're on your own!

You could also add an easter egg in your script: just after the `while` line, add:

```
[[ ${nbh[0],,} = gorilla ]] && { echo "banana"; continue; }
[[ ${nbh[0],,} = banana ]] && { echo "gorilla"; continue; }
```

Cheers!