# accepting the default value using a while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am trying to make this piece of code accept either user given 4 value or a "/" to accept the default value.

```
#!/bin/bash
$komp=1
while [ ${#nbh[@]} -ne `expr 4 \* $komp` || ${nbh[0]} -ne "/" ]
do
  echo "Enter 4 element or / to accept default"
  read -a nbh
  if [ ${#nbh[@]} -ne `expr 4 \* $komp` || ${nbh[0]} -ne "/"  ]
  then 
    echo "Wrong!!"
  else
    if [ nbh -eq "/" ]
    then
      declare -a nbh=('1' '0' '1' '1')
    fi
  fi
done
```

In present situation, it is giving error:

```
./mini.sh: line 3: [: missing `]'
./mini.sh: line 3: -ne: command not found
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Oh dear... your bash style looks like you want to win an obfuscated code contest. Or maybe this will also compile in another language?

Comment: I am not an bash expert...just learning. Can you show me a better way?

Comment: Did you actually spend some time on the [answer I provided to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687300/check-user-input-for-errors-in-bash-script/19687700#19687700)?

Comment: yes...but may be time to check a book again

Comment: I think you should learn about quoting properly.

Comment: To fix line 3, either use `[[` and `]]` in place of `[` and `]` (different test operators; different allowed syntaxes), or use the `-o` operator in place of `||` (the 'or' notation for the `[` operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

komp=1
default=(1 0 1 1)
prompt="Enter 4 elements or / to accept default: "

valid_input=0
while ((!valid_input)) && read -a nbh -p "$prompt"; do
    if ((${#nbh[@]}==1)) && [[ ${nbh[0]} = / ]]; then
        for ((i=0,nbh=();i<komp;++i)); do nbh+=( "${default[@]}" ); done
    fi
    if ((${#nbh[@]} != 4*komp)); then
        echo "Wrong!!"
        continue
    fi
    valid_input=1
done

if ((!valid_input)); then
    echo >&2 "There was an error reading your input. Do you have a banana jammed in your keyboard?"
    exit 1
fi

# Here, all is good
```

Now you'll also want to check that user's inputs are valid numbers.

Please read (and understand) [the answer I provided to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687300/check-user-input-for-errors-in-bash-script/19687700#19687700). (if you actually had done so, you wouldn't have asked this question).

Comment: Thanks for the code. this one is straight forward. Just one more question. This will fail with default `"/"` if `komp>1`. can you kindly show me how I can copy the default `nbh` to `komp` times? e.g, `nbh=komp*('1' '0' '1' '1')`
Sorry for bothering.

Comment: @Rudra right! What do you want when `komp` is not 1? e.g., if `komp=2` do you want `nbh=(1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1)` for the default?

Comment: yes. 
so, for `komp` being a variable with value, say, `n`, this `1 0 1 1` set will repeat `n` times.

Comment: @Rudra done. I've put the default values at the top, for easier maintenance (and customization/modification).

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem is that you can't do a boolean expression that way.

```
while [ expr1 || expr2 ]  # WRONG
```

does not work because the shell parses it as two commands: `[ expr` (the command `[` with one argument "expr1") and `expr2 ]` (the command `expr2` with one argument "]").  This is an error, because the `[` command requires that its last argument be the literal string `]`.  It is easier to understand the syntax if you use the `test` command instead of `[`, but either of the following will work:

```
while test expr1 || test expr2
while [ expr1 ] || [ expr2 ]
while [ expr1 -o expr2 ]
while test expr1 -o expr2
```